# How to show smart app banner on top of your site that redirects to your app store

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs

I am using this library **"smart-app-banner": "^2.0.0",** to show the smart app banner, which it works fine, but the problem I have is this.

I have created an android app with a webview which points to my site, the thing is that the smart app banner still shows into the webview, which it does not make any sense to send the user to download the app as he already using the app.

How can I hide it from webview and only show on my site when they visit the site from a mobile device.

Currently I use this peace of code:

```
  <script src="assets/js/smart-app-banner.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      new SmartBanner({
          daysHidden: 15,   // days to hide banner after close button is clicked (defaults to 15)
          daysReminder: 90, // days to hide banner after "VIEW" button is clicked (defaults to 90)
          appStoreLanguage: 'us', // language code for the App Store (defaults to user's browser language)
          title: 'Winnova',
          author: 'Starcut LLC',
          button: 'VIEW',
          store: {
              ios: 'On the App Store',
              android: 'In Google Play',
              windows: 'In Windows store'
          },
          price: {
              ios: 'FREE',
              android: 'FREE',
              windows: 'FREE'
          }
          // , theme: '' // put platform type ('ios', 'android', etc.) here to force single theme on all device
          // , icon: '' // full path to icon image if not using website icon image
          // , force: 'ios' // Uncomment for platform emulation
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: Did you use a library to create your app, like Cordova?

Comment: I created app using Android, natively, so I just added a webview to point to my site

Comment: You could set a custom user-agent `webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("my-android-app");` and test for it before initializing the SmartBanner script.

Comment: I think this would work, can u add it as an actual answer so I can accept if working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom User Agent in the WebView settings and use this in your web application.

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("my-android-app");
```

Then in your web application you can do something like this:

```
<script>
if (navigator.userAgent !== 'my-android-app') {
  new SmartBanner({
   ...
  })
}
</script>
```

Be aware though, if you use web Analytics I wouldn't change the User Agent.